# Compact a hex number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, sse

Is there a clever (ie: branchless) way to "compact" a hex number.  Basically move all the 0s all to one side?

eg:

```
0x10302040 -> 0x13240000
```

or

```
0x10302040 -> 0x00001324
```

I looked on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) but didn't see anything.

It's for a SSE numerical pivoting algorithm.  I need to remove any pivots that become 0.  I can use `_mm_cmpgt_ps` to find good pivots, `_mm_movemask_ps` to convert that in to a mask, and then bit hacks to get something like the above.  The hex value gets munged in to a mask for a `_mm_shuffle_ps` instruction to perform a permutation on the SSE 128 bit register.

Comment: The [BMI2 instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets) does exactly what you want - but only for bits. Perhaps there's a way to hack it to work on groups of 4 bits.

Comment: `_pext_u32` with a mask of 0xf0f0f0f0 does this, if you want to do it with SSE you can of course shift/mask/recombine

Comment: @harold I think the problem here is that the OP doesn't know where the zeros will be. But you could generate that mask with a few bit hacks.

Comment: That would make it more interesting. Well OP, clarify your question please

Comment: Does your processor support conditional execution of instructions?

Comment: I don't know where the 0s will be before hand, no.  They're the result of some other SSE math.  BMI2 is great, but I'd like to support older SSE hardware if I can.  Writing branching code is possible, but there's a certain elegance to branchless code, so if that's an option all the better.

Comment: What should happen with `0x01200340`? What good is this compacting if you can't extract the original number?

Comment: _mm_shuffle_ps takes an immediate, where every 2 bits form an index, not every 4. So you will need to switch on this mask if you want to execute this instruction with the required immediate value (you can’t pass a variable to it). If you're going to do all that anyway, why not just switch on the value returned from _mm_movemask_ps without further bit munging to execute _mm_shuffle_ps with the correct immediate value?

Comment: @RedX: I realize you probably want OP to answer this. But I'm feeling pretty certain the answer is 0x00001234. OP correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compute mask for `_pext`:

```
mask = arg;
mask |= (mask << 1) & 0xAAAAAAAA | (mask >> 1) & 0x55555555;
mask |= (mask << 2) & 0xCCCCCCCC | (mask >> 2) & 0x33333333;
```

First do bit-or on pairs of bits, then on quads. Masks prevent shifted values from overflowing to other digits.

After computing mask this way or harold's way (which is probably faster) you don't need the full power of `_pext`, so if targeted hardware doesn't support it you can replace it with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    stay_mask = mask & (~mask - 1);
    arg = arg & stay_mask | (arg >> 4) & ~stay_mask;
    mask = stay_mask | (mask >> 4);
}
```

Each iteration moves all nibbles one digit to the right if there is some space. `stay_mask` marks bits that are in their final positions. This uses somewhat less operations than Hacker's Delight solution, but might still benefit from branching.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing we can use `_pext_u32`, the issue then is computing a mask that has an F for every nibble that isn't zero. I'm not sure what the *best* approach is, but you can compute the OR of the 4 bits of the nibble and then "spread" it back out to F's like this:

```
// calculate horizontal OR of every nibble
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
// clean up junk
x &= 0x11111111;
// spread
x *= 0xF;
```

Then use that as the mask of `_pext_u32`.

`_pext_u32` can be emulated by this (taken from Hacker's Delight, figure 7.6)

```
unsigned compress(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
   unsigned mk, mp, mv, t; 
   int i; 

   x = x & m;           // Clear irrelevant bits. 
   mk = ~m << 1;        // We will count 0's to right. 

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      mp = mk ^ (mk << 1);             // Parallel prefix. 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 2); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 4); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 8); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 16); 
      mv = mp & m;                     // Bits to move. 
      m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i));   // Compress m. 
      t = x & mv; 
      x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i));     // Compress x. 
      mk = mk & ~mp; 
   } 
   return x; 
}
```

But that's a bit of a disaster. It's probably better to just resort to branching code then.

Answer (score 2):

```
uint32_t fun(uint32_t val) {
  uint32_t retVal(0x00);
  uint32_t sa(28);

  for (int sb(28); sb >= 0; sb -= 4) {
    if (val & (0x0F << sb)) {
      retVal |= (0x0F << sb) << (sa - sb)
      sa -= 4;
    }
  } 

  return retVal;
}
```

I *think* this (or something similar) is what you're looking for. Eliminating the 0 nibbles within a number. I've not debugged it, and it would only works on one side atm.

Comment: I love your usage of variable names, now what are `sa` and `sb` used for?

Comment: I'm on my lunch break so didn't spend much time on this. The sa is to keep track of how many bits you're shifting the nibble in the result. sb, is the number of bits you're shifting the mask in the value. Taking the difference of them gives you how many bits you need to shift to eliminate the 0's between the nibble you're checking and the nibble you're attempting to 'fill'.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP wants a branchless and performant method. This is just the straight-forward approach which the OP probably already has.

Comment: Bah, missed the branchless bit.

Comment: Yes, A for effort, but I'm specifically looking for something branchless.

Answer (score 2):

If your processor supports conditional instruction execution, you may get a benefit from this algorithm:

```
uint32_t compact(uint32_t orig_value)
{
    uint32_t mask = 0xF0000000u;  // Mask for isolating a hex digit.
    uint32_t new_value = 0u;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) // 8 hex digits
    {
      if (orig_value & mask == 0u)
      {
          orig_value = orig_value << 4; // Shift the original value by 1 digit
      }
      new_value |= orig_value & mask;
      mask = mask >> 4;  // next digit
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

This looks like a good candidate for loop unrolling.

The algorithm assumes that when the original value is shifted left, zeros are shifted in, filling in the "empty" bits.

**Edit 1:**
On a processor that supports conditional execution of instructions, the shifting of the original value would be conditionally executed depending on the result of the ANDing of the original value and the mask.  Thus no branching, only ignored instructions.

Answer (score -2):

I came up with the following solution. Please take a look, maybe it will help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class IsZero
{
public:
    bool operator ()(char c)
    {
        return '0' == c;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 0x01020334; //IMPUT

    ostringstream my_sstream;

    my_sstream << hex << a;

    string str = my_sstream.str();
    int base_str_length = str.size();

    cout << "Input hex: " << str << endl;

    str.insert(remove_if(begin(str), end(str), IsZero()), count_if(begin(str), end(str), IsZero()), '0');
    str.replace(begin(str) + base_str_length, end(str), "");

    cout << "Processed hex: " << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input hex: 1020334
Processed hex: 1233400
```

Comment: The question looks to be asking for an algorithm that operates on numbers, not strings. Also, a branchless algorithm was preferred. The `remove_if` and `count_if` very likely have branches inside of them. Decompiling might be illuminating here.