# How to filter a std::integer_sequence

Tags: c++, c++17

If I theoretically have a sequence of integers like

```
std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>
```

How can I filter it with some compile-time predicate to get a potentially smaller `std::integer_sequence<int, ...>`?

For the sake of argument, let's say that I want only the even values,
which leads to the question of "How can I make the following static_assert (or something close) pass?"

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8>,
              decltype(FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>{}))>, 
              "Integer sequences should be equal");
```

<sup>This question was inspired by thinking about how we might accomplish removing duplicates between two bitsets ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720249/detecting-matching-bits-in-c#comment70636187_41720249)), assuming we could represent the bitsets as `integer_sequences` containing only 0 and 1. Bonus points if you can solve that one in this manner, too</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Edit 2

After some back and forth on Barry's answer, I've come up with the following answer that merges the concepts and handles some empty-sequence edge cases ([Full code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aXar83yRPdBj4b0f)):

We are allowed to pass a predicate to a function only if it is a `constexpr` lambda, as only literal types are allowed in [`constexpr` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), and normal free-floating functions aren't literal types (although I suppose you could wrap one within your lambda).

Our generic filter function will accept a sequence and a predicate, and return a new sequence. We will use [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) to handle empty sequence cases (which also requires the [`maybe_unused`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) attribute on the predicate, because it's unused) :

```
template<class INT, INT... b, class Predicate>
constexpr auto Filter(std::integer_sequence<INT, b...>, [[maybe_unused]] Predicate pred)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(b) > 0) // non empty sequence
       return concat_sequences(FilterSingle(std::integer_sequence<INT, b>{}, pred)...);
    else // empty sequence case
        return std::integer_sequence<INT>{};
}
```

The `Filter` function calls `FilterSingle` for each element in the provided sequence, and concatenates the result of all of them:

```
template<class INT, INT a, class Predicate>
constexpr auto FilterSingle(std::integer_sequence<INT, a>, Predicate pred)
{
    if constexpr (pred(a))
        return std::integer_sequence<INT, a>{};
    else
        return std::integer_sequence<INT>{};
}
```

To concatenate sequences, the basic approach is thus:

```
template<typename INT, INT... s, INT... t>
constexpr std::integer_sequence<INT,s...,t...>
concat_sequences(std::integer_sequence<INT, s...>, std::integer_sequence<INT, t...>){
    return {};
}
```

Although because of template expansion we'll have more than 2 sequences a lot of time, so we need a recursive case:

```
template<typename INT, INT... s, INT... t, class... R>
constexpr auto
concat_sequences(std::integer_sequence<INT, s...>, std::integer_sequence<INT, t...>, R...){
    return concat_sequences(std::integer_sequence<INT,s...,t...>{}, R{}...);
}
```

And since we may try to concatenate an empty sequence with nothing (can happen if no elements pass the filter), we need another base case:

```
template<typename INT>
constexpr std::integer_sequence<INT>
concat_sequences(std::integer_sequence<INT>){
    return {};
}
```

Now, for our predicate we will use a [`constexpr` lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Note that we do not need to specify it as `constexpr` explicitly because it already satisfies the criteria to automatically become `constexpr`

```
auto is_even = [](int _in) {return _in % 2 == 0;};
```

So our full test looks like this:

```
auto is_even = [](int _in) {return _in % 2 == 0;};
using expected_type = std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8>;
using test_type = std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>;
constexpr auto result = Filter(test_type{}, is_even);
using result_type = std::decay_t<decltype(result)>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<expected_type, result_type>, "Integer sequences should be equal");
```

---

#### Previous approach

My approach is repeatedly construct and concatenate sub-sequences, where the base case (sequence of one) will either return an empty sequence or the same sequence if the predicate is satisfied.

For writing the predicate, I'll take advantage of C++17's [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) for defining a predicate.

Predicate:

```
// base case; empty sequence
template<class INT>
constexpr auto FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<INT>)
{
    return std::integer_sequence<INT>{};
}

// base case; one element in the sequence
template<class INT, INT a>
constexpr auto FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<INT, a>)
{
    if constexpr (a % 2 == 0)
        return std::integer_sequence<INT, a>{};
    else
        return std::integer_sequence<INT>{};
}

// recursive case
template<class INT, INT a, INT... b>
constexpr auto FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<INT, a, b...>)
{
    return concat_sequence(FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<INT, a>{}), 
                           FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<INT, b...>{}));
}
```

Concatenation logic:

```
template <typename INT, INT ...s, INT ...t>
constexpr auto
concat_sequence(std::integer_sequence<INT,s...>,std::integer_sequence<INT,t...>){
   return std::integer_sequence<INT,s...,t...>{};
}
```

And the test:

```
int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8>, decltype(FilterEvens(std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>{}))>, "Integer sequences should be equal");
}
```

[Live Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SwLOQTT6cmkxp0QT)

---

#### Edit:

I used this approach to solve the "Bonus" question for removing matched bits here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727221/27678

Answer (score 16):

Filtering a sequence is equivalent to transforming a sequence of values into a sequence of sequences of at most one value and then concatenating them. That is, filtering the even values from `<0,1,2,3>` would be the same as transforming that into the sequence `<<0>,<>,<2>,<>>` and concatenating to yield `<0,2>`.

With C++17, this takes remarkably little code. We'll start with our own value and sequence type (you can easily convert a `std::integer_sequence` to a `value_sequence`):

```
template <auto >
struct value { };

template <auto... Vals>
struct value_sequence { };
```

The reason we use our own is so we can add operators to it. Like `+`:

```
template <auto... As, auto... Bs>
constexpr value_sequence<As..., Bs...> operator+(value_sequence<As...>,
                                                 value_sequence<Bs...> )
{
    return {};
}
```

We'll use that for concatenation. Next, we add a function to transform a single value into a sequence of zero or one element:

```
template <auto Val, class F>
constexpr auto filter_single(value<Val>, F predicate) {
    if constexpr (predicate(Val)) {
        return value_sequence<Val>{};
    }
    else {
        return value_sequence<>{};
    }
}
```

And lastly, we just need our top-level `filter` to put it all together:

```
template <auto... Vals, class F>
constexpr auto filter(value_sequence<Vals...>, F predicate) {
    return (filter_single(value<Vals>{}, predicate) + ...);
}
```

Usage from the original example:

```
constexpr auto evens = filter(
    value_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>{},
    [](int i) constexpr { return i%2 == 0; });
```

How cool is C++17!

Comment: I like this. The slightly tricky part is that `predicate` can't really have state. Also, the explicit `constexpr` on the lambda is unnecessary.

Comment: @Barry : I think the proposed [Boost.Outcome](https://ned14.github.io/boost.outcome/) would work fine, and already has both member function and operator-based chaining available.

Comment: @Barry : It has a monadic (inc. chainable) `pair<bool, NewPredicate>`, or rather you can easily compose one. You get your nice chaining semantics for free. (My experience with the library is limited but very positive; I have no investment here.)

Comment: I like the idea of using a constexpr lambda as the predicate, although gcc needs a little catching up for this to work (right now get an ICE): http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2m8MRkTyMwbYUyUJ

What is strange is the choice of `operator+` as the concatenation operator for value sequences. One might think instead they would imply some kind of mathematical addition instead (esp. with the analog to integer sequences)

Comment: @Barry: I'm also a little confused regarding the predicate parameter to `filter` and `filter_single`. If I instead use a `constexpr bool` function, gcc tells me that it's not a constant expression ([link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LiAmgxrDGkj1QWZF)). That `F` becomes `bool (*)(int)` makes sense, and my intuition tells me that it *could* be a constant expression, so is gcc wrong here?

Comment: I suppose a function pointer wouldn't qualify as a literal type and thus couldn't be an arg to a constexpr function (so you'd need to specify it as a non-type template arg). It should really be a constexpr lambda as you've done.

Comment: I've merged yours and my answer into one that does the trick: [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/81WusFnYQCXzpGMC)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution leveraging tuples:

```
template <auto Pred, class Type, Type... I>
struct filter_integer_sequence_impl
{
    template <class... T>
    static constexpr auto Unpack(std::tuple<T...>)
    {
        return std::integer_sequence<Type, T::value...>();
    }

    template <Type Val>
    using Keep = std::tuple<std::integral_constant<Type, Val>>;
    using Ignore = std::tuple<>;
    using Tuple = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::conditional_t<(*Pred)(I), Keep<I>, Ignore>()...));
    using Result = decltype(Unpack(Tuple()));
};

template <auto Pred, class Type, Type... I>
constexpr auto filter_integer_sequence(std::integer_sequence<Type, I...>)
{
    return typename filter_integer_sequence_impl<Pred, Type, I...>::Result();
}

template <class Pred, class Type, Type... I>
constexpr auto filter_integer_sequence(std::integer_sequence<Type, I...> sequence, Pred)
{
    return filter_integer_sequence<(Pred*)nullptr>(sequence);
}
```

Used like this:

```
constexpr auto predicate = [](int val) { return (val % 2) == 0; };

constexpr auto start = std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>();
constexpr auto filtered = filter_integer_sequence(start, predicate);
constexpr auto expected = std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8>();

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(filtered), decltype(expected)>);
```

The second overload of `filter_integer_sequence` is only necessary for C++17 which doesn't allow us to use lambdas for non-type template parameters. C++20 lifts that restriction, so in that case only the first overload is needed. Note that the first overload is still necessary in C++17 for handling regular function pointers.

Like the other solutions here, the second overload only works for non-capturing lambdas. This is why we can safely evaluate `(*(Pred*)nullptr)(I)` as constexpr since the lambda body doesn't actually use the `this` pointer.

Comment: Clever use of non type class template arguments