# Compile time std::index_sequence with custom values

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to create an `std::index_sequence` which holds multiple of given number.

Let's say I want to hold values like `0, 3, 6, 9, ...` or `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...`.

How to create such a custom sequence?

I want to use it by giving number of values to generate and step between consecutive values.

Comment: `std::index_sequence<0,2,4,6,8,10,12>` ? Its unclear what problem you encountered. Please show what you tried.

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to filter a std::integer_sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723704/how-to-filter-a-stdinteger-sequence)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I want to use it by giving number of values to generate and step between consecutive values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a "normal" index sequence and multiply it by `M` as below:

```cpp
template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
auto make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of() {
    return []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::index_sequence<(I * M)...>{};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Example: You could create a sequence of 5 indices as multiples of 3 like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto is = make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of<3, 5>();
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<std::index_sequence<0, 3, 6, 9, 12>, decltype(is)>);
}
```

Pre C++20 version:

```cpp
namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t M, std::size_t... I>
    auto helper(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::index_sequence<(I * M)...>{};    
    }
}  // namespace detail

template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
auto make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of() {
    return detail::helper<M>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

---

If you want the *type* instead of an object, you could just hide the creation and use `decltype` to figure out the type. Here's pre C++20 version of that:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <std::size_t M, std::size_t... I>
auto helper(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::index_sequence<(I * M)...>{};
}
}  // namespace detail

template <std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of =
    decltype(detail::helper<M>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
```

Comment: note that `std::make_index_sequence` is a type while your `make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of` is a function. Not really an issue, perhaps even more convenient for the typical use case

Comment: Not too hard to fix the type vs function thing `using make_index_sequence_as_multiple_of = decltype([]{ ... same body... }());`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai True, and yes, I'm thinking this would cover the common use-cases.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Yes, that's a very simple solution to that.